# Http request through Cntlm proxy.

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ntlm

I am trying to make an HTTP request through Cntlm proxy on NodeJs, and I can't make it work. This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'http://127.0.0.1',
  port: 3128,
  path: "http://www.google.com",
  headers: {
    Host: "www.google.com"
  }
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.stack);
});
```

I always get the following error:

```
Got error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that options.host shouldn't have protocol ('http://'). Deleting that gives me a 302-Found. Just have to change www.google.com to a non-redirecting URL to get 200-Ok.